# Apache access to NTFS linked folders in linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

Using Apache2/PHP in Debian jessie, when I want to make a new subsection in document folder of Apache (/var/www) I simply create a link to an external folder where my php files exist and simply change the owner and permissions of the folder as follow and it works perfect.

```
ln -s /home/myname/mynewcode /var/www/test1
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/myname/mynewcode
chmod -R 755 /home/myname/mynewcode
```

Then I could access http://localhost/test1

But when the real folder that I want to link it, is on a NTFS partition since chown and chmod do not work, I do modify the /etc/fstab by adding the following code, therefore my NTFS partitions will mount with the required permissions and owner.

```
UUID=XXDDXDDXDDDXDDDD /media/myname/lable ntfs user,exec,uid=www-data,gid=www-data 0 2

ln -s /media/myname/lable/mynewcode2 /var/www/test2
```

But still I do get the permission error from Apache2 and I don't know what to do!!

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /test2 on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Can you provide more information as to the nature of the NTFS drive you're trying to work with? Is this an NTFS drive physically connected to the server? USB or internal? As a network share? If network, is there a domain controller? If on a domain, using Active Directory permissions for the share?

Comment: The NTFS drive is one of internal disks and there is no domain controller but sometimes a windows IIS uses that and I could not share it via windows.

Comment: So there's a virtual machine involved here?

Comment: No the server is a multi-boot one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot offer a 100% working solution but I have two points which you might want to check.

First, try adding `umask` to the `fstab` line. I think this causes the permission error. `umask` adds correct permission to all files (644) and directories (755) when mounting. **You must remount the NTFS folder!**

```
UUID=XXDDXDDXDDDXDDDD /media/myname/lable ntfs user,exec,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,umask=022 0 2
```

You need to make sure, the `www-data` user is able to `cd` into the destination folder:

```
sudo su www-data -s bash && cd /media/myname/lable
```

Second, make sure "FollowSymlinks" is allowed on the specific folder, I think you have that already, but try anyways:

```
<Directory "/media/myname/lable/">
    Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the solution does not work for me and I still get the Forbidden error I add the umask and restart the OS and I also double check the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf for FollowSymlinks and every thing seemed OK. but the permission error remains.

Comment: Log into your server, type `sudo su www-data -c bash` and then try `cd /var/www/your_symlinked_directory` and `cat some_file.html`. This way, you see when there is a permission error somewhere.

Comment: Apache 2.4 uses a different access control. You have to replace `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all` with `Require all granted`. For more information see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html

Comment: sudo su www-data -c bash => This account is currently not available.

Comment: while trying `sudo su www-data -c bash` => "This account is currently not available." I think the user does not have a  login policy and I don't know if it is safe to remove it and How to do it. also I have tried `Required all granted` and it is still gives the same error. I also tried this scenario in a clean installation of Debian to make sure if other configurations do not interfere and get the same permission error.

Comment: You should be able to use `sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: I think `www-data` is disabled in `/etc/passwd`, I have it enabled on all servers but disabled remote / SSH login for `www-data`.

Comment: thanks `skroczek`, your guidance let me direct to the error `www-data@AM-Notebook:~$ cd test=>
bash: cd: test: Permission denied` I could not enter the test folder which is a safe link and the permission for the the directory is `drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  5 00:31 test` is there any other step that I could solve the error. and by the way sorry for late answers I do not have access to the system all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the NTFS partition belongs to a Windows machine? You can share it in Windows and mount it in Debian with

`mount -t cifs //windows_host/share /var/www/test2 uid=xxx,gid=xxx,rw,sec=ntlmv 0 0`

So you don't need to deal with NTFS directly.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. and yes the NTFS partition belongs to Windows machine but the machine is not always available so I could not use sharing.

Comment: No worries. This might be a silly question: you said you can't use sharing but how do you mount it the other way when it's not available?

Comment: well I use it on a multi-boot server sometimes the system booted with windwos and IIS uses that hard disk and most offen debian is awake using apache

Comment: I don't have an NTFS to test but I guess you can use rsync to sync all content to the native linux partition when debian boots up? not perfect but at least you won't be blocked by NTFS permission errors.

Comment: wise idea, and what about when I do changes in debian and want to sync the partition in windows. I think there are only tools for mounting ext3 partitions as readonly ones in windows.

Comment: maybe sync it back to NTFS just before debian shuts down? 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown